# Command-line ping is low but in-game ping is thousands of milliseconds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

Why is my ping to `eu.mineplex.com` apparently about 40 ms but when I go in-game and check (with labymod/the5zigmod) it is between 700 and 3000 all the time?

No other server seems to have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to run a tracert to eu.mineplex.com and see which node is (i would assume) dropping your packets.

Dropped packets in MC are especially nasty since if the client doesn't get a server response within a certain time frame it attempts to resend its packet.  This essentially overloads everything and you basically just never (or after a very long delay) get your response from the server and it's already invalidated by something else.

Once you have the node you can try submitting a request to your ISP to assign you a traffic route that doesn't hit that node.

Answer (score -1):

Connecting to the server takes 40ms but staying connected to the server takes 700-3000ms. This might be beacuse of your connection between your internet and the server.